# DateTimePicker in C# WPF DateTimeChanged Firing Twice

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I have a DateTimePicker control in a popup in C# (.Net Framework 4) and when I change the value the DateTimeChanged fires twice with the following values (changing the date to 9/16/2013 11:15AM as an example):

First time firing, DateTimePicker .SelectedDateTime.ToLocalTime() = 9/16/2013 00:00AM
Second time firing. DateTimePicker .SelectedDateTime.ToLocalTime() = 9/16/2013 11:15AM

Is this normal behavior? If so is there an event that I can look at that only fires once and would give me the 9/16/2013 11:15AM result?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doing some more digging I found out this was a custom third party control that has a bug in it so closing the questions.